# dateSelect event not being executed in p:calendar

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've been trying to solve this issue but I can't get it solved. The issue is that I have a calendar with a dateSelect event ready to be fired whenever the user selects a date in the popup calendar, but the listener is never executed. Syntax is correct from my point of view.

form.xhtml calendar code.

```
                        <p:calendar value="#{travel.departureDate}" required="true"
                            id="departureDate" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                            onfocus="$('#ui-datepicker-div td').unbind();" readonly="true">
                            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" actionListener="#{travelControl.alterDate}"
                            update=":main-form:departureDate" />
                        </p:calendar>
```

Everything is inside a form and a panelGrid container.

The bean method is the following one.

```
public void alterDate(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Hour [Pre] "
            + travel.getDepartureDate().toString()); //debug

    travel.setDepartureDate((Date) event.getObject());

    System.out.println("Hour [Post] "
            + travel.getDepartureDate().toString()); //debug
}
```

Once the date is selected, the value of the text field changes for a moment and then resets to the one in the bean as it wasn't changed due to the event not being properly fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use listener instead of actionListener:

```
listener ="#{travelControl.alterDate}"
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the code in your alterDate method and just spitting out a log message to see if it's getting called at all.  I duplicated your code and changing "actionListener" to "listener" go it to work.  In your method, where do you get 'travel' from?

Comment: I get travel from here. `@ManagedProperty(value = "#{travel}")
 private BeanTravel travel;` . I have those .out.println to check if its executed and I get nothing when selecting a date.

Comment: remove the onfocus and readonly bits and see if that helps; my code doesn't work with either of those added: `onfocus="$('#ui-datepicker-div td').unbind();" readonly="true"`

Comment: Oh so that was the problem, thanks a lot! But as it is a necessary part so the user can just pick the date from the calendar, how can I solve that? Another ajax event for 'onclose'?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow that.  What do you need the control to do?

Comment: Whenever the user picks a date from the calendar, the departureDate from the BeanTravel is modified and the form is updated, so the other two calendars that are in the form are notified and their mindate and maxdate attributes are updated. But, the textfield for the calendars must be readonly and the user shouldn't be able to write anything on them, just the date selected via the calendar.

Comment: Primefaces has an attribute for that: `readonlyInput="true" `

Comment: Yes but with that attribute they can still erase the date and leave the textfield emtpy.

Comment: I'm using PF 5.1 and that attribute makes the input field just a display field.  You can't click into it or delete the text in it.

Comment: Mmm... it seems that in 5.3 is completly different, maybe there's a bug in the attribute in this version.

Comment: I don't see that attribute used in their showcase, so I can't test it out.  I'd check their forums to see if anyone else is having issues with it. http://forum.primefaces.org/